# NoReverseMatch error when loading profile detail page

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I'm trying to load a template that views the details of my custom UserEntry profile. When I go to the URL that was supposed to load my class-based view, I get this error from Django:

```
Reverse for 'UserProfile' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/profile/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

**views.py:**

```
class UserProfileView(DetailView):
    model = UserEntry
    template_name = 'userprofile_app/userprofile.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        users = UserEntry.objects.all()
        context = super(UserProfileView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)     
        page_user = get_object_or_404(UserEntry, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context['page_user'] = page_user
        return context
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('entry/', UserRegistrationView.as_view(), name='UserEntry'),
    path('profile/<int:pk>/', UserProfileView.as_view(), name='UserProfile'),
]
```

**Template:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'UserProfile' UserEntry.id %}">EDIT PROFILE</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
```

Models.py

```
class UserEntry(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=264)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is UserEntry.id is empty that's why its throwing error. Make sure you are passing correct UserEntry Object into the Template

Comment: Can i see your UserEntry model ?

Comment: Are you passing UserEntry object into your Template ?

Comment: Url not getting UserEntry.id.

Comment: how should the UserEntry object need to be passed

Comment: Which view is rendering your mentioned Template ?

Comment: UserProfileView

Comment: Try using object.id instead UserEntry.id

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign user id to variable name which you use(pk) in urls.py

pk = page_user.id

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'UserProfile' pk=page_user.id %}">EDIT PROFILE</a>
```